# How to configure mail for local use only

Tags: mail

After installing mailx I need to configure it for local only use.
How do you change the default configuration.

Comment: _local use_ meaning?

Comment: local to my computer -  not on internet. In general my question is how to configure the mail program to change the default configuration. Right now it does not work.

Comment: Did you install the package  `mailutils`?

Comment: Yes and I chose default configuration no change . It is not working and I only need it to send mail to users on my computer network.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "It is not working"? What exactly have you tried and what step(s) did not work as expected?

Comment: The following   mail don

Comment: Mail don This is a test Ctrl D Cannot send message:process exited with non zero status

Answer (score 0):

mailx needs to be configured in order to receive messages from local users. The easiest way to configure mailx is to install sendmail with `sudo apt-get sendmail` and the sendmail program will work for 3 to 5 minutes when it is being installed and it will configure mailx automatically. `sendmail` requires additional configuration to send mail via the internet, which I will skip here because your question is about how to use the mailx program to send a message to a local user.

Then type `mailx` to start the program and after the `?` prompt type the number of a message to read it in the terminal. It can take a few minutes to get a notification that you have received a new message after it is sent. Then you will see that the new message has been added to the list of messages in your inbox.

If you get the error message: `cannot send message: Process exited with non-zero status` that means that mail did not exit correctly. The way to avoid getting this error message is to make the next line after the end of the body of the message a newline containing only the **.** character and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This indicates the end of the message. Then press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to quit composing the message.